# How do I add composite MySQL Indexes with denormalization and JOINS?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, index-tuning, clustered-index

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE base_event (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    created_by ... -- some columns
);

CREATE TABLE transaction_events (
    event_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    transaction_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    merchant_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,   
    merchant_city VARCHAR (...) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -- Denormalize
    customer_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    customer_ip_address VARCHAR(...) NULL DEFAULT NULL, -- Denormalize
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES base_event(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (merchant_id) REFERENCES merchants(id),
);

CREATE TABLE customers (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_ip_address VARCHAR(...) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE merchants (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

And my `SELECT`:

```sql
(SELECT t.*, c.name AS customer_name ...
FROM transaction_events t
JOIN customers c ON t.customer_id = c.id
JOIN merchants m ON t.merchant_id = m.id
WHERE t.customer_ip_address = 'abc' AND t.transaction_time > 'abc')
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT t.*, c.name AS customer_name ...
FROM transaction_events t
JOIN customers c ON t.customer_id = c.id
JOIN merchants m ON t.merchant_id = m.id
WHERE t.merchant_city = 'abc' AND t.transaction_time > 'abc')
```

And my indexes are:

```sql
ALTER TABLE transaction_events 
ADD INDEX index_1 (customer_ip_address, transaction_time),
ADD INDEX index_2 (merchant_city, transaction_time);
```

1. My query is in this form to avoid `OR`.
2. I've denormalized to a degree for the sake of the indexes.
3. I do not need to reference my `base_event` table for this query.
4. The relation with `transaction_events` to `customers` and `merchants` is not 1-to-1 but 1-to-0-or-1.

My questions:

1. I can get rid of the wildcard, but `transaction_events` has around 20 columns (Would it help creating any further indexes to speed up the query?
2. Do I need to put any other composite indexes (that potentially reference my FKs) to further improve this query?

Comment: Thanks for writing such a clear and complete question.  And welcome to dba.stackexchange.  I look forward to answering more questions from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clauses refer to `t`, so it is very likely that the Optimizer will start with `t` in each `SELECT`.  You have the optimal indexes for them.

Then it needs to reach into the other two tables (`merchants` and `customers`) and get 1 (or 0) row from them.  Those tables have the optimal index for the `JOIN`, namely `PRIMARY KEY(id)` in each case.  (The FKs do not play any role in this query.)

`t.*` might slow things down if it is fetching large `TEXT` columns that you then ignore.

Since you need all the columns, then the only possible inefficiency is if each `SELECT` is fetching the same row redundantly, only to be dedupped by `UNION DISTINCT`.  I *think* that that problem is not worth fixing.  (The fix would be to have the `UNION` find and dedup only `t.id`; then join back to `t` to get the other 19 columns.  The cost of the extra work may outweigh the benefit; I cannot tell.)

Comment: Just to let you know, `SELECT * FROM transaction_events t JOIN (SELECT t.event_id
FROM transaction_events t
JOIN customers c ON t.customer_id = c.id
JOIN merchants m ON t.merchant_id = m.id
WHERE t.customer_ip_address = 'abc' AND t.transaction_time > 'abc')
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT t.event_id
FROM transaction_events t
JOIN customers c ON t.customer_id = c.id
JOIN merchants m ON t.merchant_id = m.id
WHERE t.merchant_city = 'abc' AND t.transaction_time > 'abc') filtered ON t.event_id = filtered.event_id` helped around 100ms.

Comment: I also created the indexes as `INDEX(customer_id , transaction_time, event_id)`. But this is mainly because we expect around 2k results from the query, from around 2-3 million.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all 20 columns from `transaction_events`? If not, then getting rid of `*` and specifying only the columns you need not only reduces the amount of data you're pulling back at one time but also reduces the chances of a sub-optimal query plan. It's possible the query plan generated will vary based on the columns in your `SELECT` clause.

You could test adding an index on the `customer_id` field and another index on the `merchant_id` field for your `JOIN` clauses and see if it improves performance and produces a better query plan. But this will require testing and comparison of the **EXPLAIN** for each case.

Comment: I do need that 20 columns, every one of them. Isn't FK already adding the indexes to that columns in InnoDB?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Yes you're right, if you're using **InnoDB** that's true, in other database systems that's not the case. You should include that in your tags.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral In regards to indexing, I don't think there's much more you can do then. Is the current performance sub-optimal?